# Add missing features to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `TRAIN` and `TEST`.  I would like to change `TRAIN` by adding the information that it contains none of the items (Y2, Y3) that are in `TEST` but not in `TRAIN`.

```
TRAIN = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                      'Y1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y4': [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

TEST  = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                      'Y1': [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
                      'Y2': [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                      'Y3': [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y4': [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]})
```

I would like:

```
TRAIN = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                      'Y1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y4': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y2': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y3': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

I tried:

```
L_TRAIN = list(TRAIN)
L_TEST  = list(TEST)

def Diff(li1, li2): 
    li_dif = [i for i in li1 + li2 if i not in li1] 
    return li_dif

L_DIFF  = Diff(L_TRAIN, L_TEST)

TRAIN[L_DIFF] = 0
```

But got:

```
KeyError: "['Y2' 'Y3'] not in index"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` doesn't support assigning a value to multiple column so you need to iterate over it one by one:

```
import pandas as pd 

TRAIN = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                      'Y1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y4': [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

TEST  = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                      'Y1': [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
                      'Y2': [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                      'Y3': [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                      'Y4': [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]})


diff_cols = set(TEST.columns)-set(TRAIN.columns)

for i in diff_cols:
    TRAIN[i] = 0

print(TRAIN)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y1  Y4  Y2  Y3                                                                                                                  
0  1   1   1   0   0                                                                                                                  
1  1   1   1   0   0                                                                                                                  
2  1   1   0   0   0                                                                                                                  
3  1   1   0   0   0                                                                                                                  
4  1   1   0   0   0                                                                                                                  
5  2   1   0   0   0                                                                                                                  
6  2   0   0   0   0
```